# Help me formulate a question

Tags: discussion

I am trying to formulate a question about queries in C#/ADO.NET, but have problem phrasing it so it is clear to the reader.

I have textbox in which user can enter query. When user presses button I wish to execute that query.

Being a beginner, I first searched MSDN documentation and online code examples so I can learn how to do this.

I have found out that one must use different command objects, depending on the type of the query.

I will use [OleDbCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and to perform the query it seems that I must know *beforehand* what type of query I am performing -> is it `SELECT` or `UPDATE` etc.

That brings me to the problem: I do not know what type of query ( `SELECT` or `UPDATE` or something else ) will be typed into textbox, so I do not know which command to execute.

Therefore I would like to ask if there is a way to read any type of query with one command only. However, I do not know how to phrase this question properly, so I do not waste everyone's time.

How should I phrase the question about the above problem, so the reader does not get confused?

Comment: The only point of confusion for me is why you don't just check whether the first word in the string is `'SELECT'`, `'UPDATE'`, etc.?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: That solution did occur to me, but I want to know if there is another way...

Comment: One option is to write something based on your current approach, make sure it works, then take it to CodeReview.SE to see if anyone can think of something neater. If you get stuck while trying to implement it, you may have a good SO question.

Comment: I agree with jonrsharpe's point. Either you have code that does exactly what you want, but you'd like to know if it can be better, in which case codereview is the way to go, or you have code that does something different than what you want and you want help fixing it, in which case stackoverflow is it. In either case, I'm puzzled by the question here: if you can provide enough information here for someone to understand your question well enough to write it for you, isn't that enough information for the question itself? The audiences are a little different, but not _that_ different! :)

Comment: I think the way you have already worded the question is just fine. Its easy to over-think it on stack overflow.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Keep things simple and short. If the user knows `OleDbCommand` already, he will likely answer. If he doesn't provide additional resources/links, but don't try to quote the whole documentation. Something along the following should be fine:

---

> ### How can I determine which `OleDbCommand` method I have to use?
>
> I want to create an interface where the user provides a SQL query and my
>   server executes it. I'm using [`OleDbCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which expects you
>   to use `ExecuteReader()`, `ExecuteNonQuery()` or `ExecuteScalar`,
>   depending on whether the query returns multiple rows, manipulates the
>   database or retrieves a single value.
>
> How can I determine from the user input which methods I have to use?

Comment: What about the title of the question> That part troubles me the most... Upvoted for now, I will officially accept if better answers don't come up. Let me wait a little... Thank you, best regards.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff: This is a community wiki post, so I won't get any reputation, so feel free to up/downvote or accept whenever you like.

Comment: @Zeta It's also Meta so you wouldn't get any rep anyway :-).

Comment: @cybermonkey: Whoops. Yep. Well, I was sure that someone would find a better formulation and wanted to keep the edit barrier low :D.